# Rails save failing validations with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**user.rb**

```
has_many :characters
accepts_nested_attributes_for :characters

after_save self.characters.create
```

**character.rb**

```
belongs_to :user

validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
validates :user, presence: true
```

**seeds.rb**

```
user = User.find_or_initialize_by(email: "barry@websmash.com")
user.characters_attributes = [{ name: "Barry", username: "barry" }]
user.save!
```

I'm trying to set up my seeds.rb file using `find_or_initialize_by` so I can run `rails db:seed` whenever I want to add attributes to records. But running `rails db:seed` gives this error:

*Validation failed: Characters username has already been taken*

How do I get validations working through the nested attributes?

Comment: why you add this code ? `after_save self.characters.create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `after_save self.characters.create`. Not only is it completely unnecessary but it triggers the validation failure since you are creating a user record without any attributes.

To validate the associated records use the [`validates_associated` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :characters
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :characters
  validates_associated :characters
end
```

This loops through the associated records and adds `characters are invalid` to the errors on the parent user record unless all the characters are valid.

If you want to display the errors for each character you have to iterate through the errors object on each nested record:

```
<%= form_with(model: user, local: true) do |form| %>
  # ...
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Characters</legend>
    <%= form.fields_for(:characters) do |cf| %>
      <% cf.object.tap do |character| %>
        <% if character.errors.any? %>
        <div class="errors">
          <h2><%= pluralize(character.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this character from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% character.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="character">
         <div class="field">
           <%= cf.label :username %>
           <%= cf.text_field :username %>
         </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

This can of course be cleaned up by creating a generic partial for the error messages.

Comment: What's the difference between `validates_associated :characters` and `validates :characters, presence: true`?

Comment: `validates_presence_of` just checks if the attribute is nil or blank.

Answer (score 0):

Here `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does what you are trying to achieve having an after save hook. So what happens here is that, when you try to save your user with the character attributes, by default (because you accepts_nested_attributes_for) both objects get saved. Then you also have a after save hook to create your characters, which tries to create the characters again, hence throwing a unique constraint validation error. You wouldn't need your after_save hook here.

Comment: This still does not answer the question "How do I get validations working through the nested attributes?". `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does not automatically run validations for the child objects.